# Building Node.js Binary with `pkg` for ARMv7 / Ubuntu 14 fails when running output with libstdc++.so.6 Error

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu-14.04, libstdc++

Cross compile? I have a device my company still manufacturers and deploys world-wide, running Ubuntu 14.04.3 ... on an ARMv7 Processor. I have a node app I'm creating for the product family, and I'd like to run it on this device as well. Tried going the whole `nvm` route to install-and-run node directly on it, but gyphy fails to build some deps from the project locally on the device. I'd really much rather use `pkg` to build a binary to deploy to the device.

If you aren't familiar, `pkg` is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

However, building the `examples/express` example from the pkg repo with pkg 4.4.9 like `pkg . --targets node10.15.3-linux-armv7 --no-bytecode` (on a linux box) and scp'ing the resulting binary over to the IOT device running the `armv7` / Ubuntu 14 setup, I get the following error when trying to run the binary:

```
./express-example: relocation error: ./express-example: symbol
_ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, 
version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

(Line wraps added to break long line)

Googling the error (specifically with regards to GLIBC and libstdc++.so.6) has gotten me nowhere. I can't figure out if the libstdc++ on the device is too old or too new. Tried updating libstdc++ but it said it was already at the latest version (for that OS.) I've got no clue where to go from here... Is there some way to compile the binary via pkg with different options, or statically link the libraries it needs instead of relying on system libraries?

Also, when I try to use a newer node version (like 10.21.0, etc) - it fails with an "unable to build" message. I know I can crosscompile regular C/C++ code on that linux box for ARM (we do that currently with Jenkins in the cloud on a linux box), so is there a way to get crosscompile working at buildtime?

Here's the error for building with 10.21:

```
[root@decidr ~/devel/pkg/examples/express]# ./node_modules/.bin/pkg . --targets node10-linux-armv7 --no-bytecode
> pkg@4.4.9
> Fetching base Node.js binaries to PKG_CACHE_PATH
  fetched-v10.21.0-linux-armv7 [                    ] 0%
> Error! 404 Not Found
  https://github.com/zeit/pkg-fetch/releases/download/v2.6/uploaded-v2.6-node-v10.21.0-linux-armv7
> Asset not found by direct link:
  {"tag":"v2.6","name":"uploaded-v2.6-node-v10.21.0-linux-armv7"}
> Not found in GitHub releases:
  {"tag":"v2.6","name":"uploaded-v2.6-node-v10.21.0-linux-armv7"}
> Building base binary from source:
  built-v10.21.0-linux-armv7
> Error! Not able to build for 'armv7' here, only for 'x64'
```

I find myself rather stuck - can't run node directly on the device, and the device won't run the `pkg`-built binary, even though it builds ARMv7 code. No idea how to proceed forward - any assistance or ideas? :)

Comment: `--debug` flag might help. I mean: `$ ./node_modules/.bin/pkg . --targets node10-linux-armv7 --no-bytecode --debug`

Comment: Maybe wrong Node version, check: [https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/810](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/810)